# Do I need a fastcgi development library in addition to mod_fcgid?

Tags: fastcgi, mod-fcgid

Do I need fastcgi development libraries in addition to mod_fcgid.

I will use mod_fcgid together with Wt (web toolkit). Cmake files of Wt is searching for an include directory for the file fcgio.h and also fcgi++ library. (It also searches for fcgi lbrary but it is mod_fcgid.so I assume).

Which development packages do include fgcio.h and fcgi++ libraries?